# How to ignore annotation when generating Getter?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, code-generation

I've created a simple Getter generator to generate an "Optional-Getter" which wraps the field inside an Optional. the problem is when the field is annotate as @Nullable the getter will also generated with @Nullable and I found that very annoying to simply remove it every time I'm generating a getter. How can I ignore the field annotation in a costume getter ?

This is my "Optional-Getter" generator.

```
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
Optional<$field.type> ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  is##
#else
  get##
#end
${name}() {
  return Optional.fromNullable($field.name);
}
```

and that's the result now when I'm generating a getter -

```
public class Class {
    @Nullable
    private String someMember;


    @Nullable
    public Optional<String> getSomeMember() {
        return Optional.fromNullable(someMember);
    }
}
```

that's the expected result -

```
public class Class {
    @Nullable
    private String someMember;



    public Optional<String> getSomeMember() {
        return Optional.fromNullable(someMember);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the plugin [CodeGenerator](https://github.com/lotabout/CodeGenerator), via their `GitHub Repository > Releases`.
The latest relase is `1.3.3`

Install the Plugin "from disk", re-start IntelliJ/Android Studio, then via `Settings > CodeGenerator`, modify the default `Getter and Setter` template with this code, and **enable** it

```
#foreach($field in $fields)
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field.element, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
#set($getter = "is${name}")
#else
#set($getter = "get${name}")
#end
#set($setter = "set${name}")
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end

#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
Optional<$field.type> ##
${getter}() {
  return Optional.fromNullable($field.name);
}

#if($field.modifierStatic)
static ##
#end
void ${setter}($field.type $paramName) {
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
    #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
    this.##
    #else
        $classname.##
    #end
#end
$field.name = $paramName;
}
#end
```

You can than use it via `Alt+ins` (or `Code > Generate`)

[image]

Customize your templates as needed, or add new ones. Enjoy ;)

---

That's something I was looking at too for IDEA. Actually since a long time. Unfortunately as of now it doesn't seem to be parameterizable.

This is the YouTrack issue which made available the automatic insertion of `@Nullable` and `@NotNull` to generated getters/setters

https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-30683

You can vote for a feature that would automatically convert to an `Optional<T>` getter, when possible

https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-201804

And you can vote for the feature that exposes the annotations to the Apache Velocity template

https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-176763

Comment: So they added this automatic annotation generation as a feature but didn't gave an option to cancel/modify it ?

Comment: @OfekRegev exactly. But they are on the "good side". Probably they didn't think about your usecase. Remember that Optional is a relatively recent standard feature.

Comment: I think they were actually looking for the simple solution and of-course it wasn't adding the annotations to the Apache Velocity template...

Comment: @OfekRegev if you're interested in plug-ins development, you might be able to create your own getter and setter generator.

Comment: I'm interested in developing a lot of things, unfortunately there're only 24 hours a day...

Comment: @OfekRegev hahaha yeah! I'll edit this answer if I'll get more info about this issue.

Comment: Alright,thanks. I'll mark it as correct because unfortunately it's probably the closest I'll get to the solution.